Doxygen/GraphViz collab diagram for C# doesn't show links for collections
I have a C# project. I use Doxygen and GraphViz for generating collaboration diagrams.
When a class uses a List (e.g. public List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();) the diagram does not generate a link between the current class an the Item class.
For example:

When a class uses an Array (e.g. Item[] Items = new Item[10];) the diagram shows a link between the current class and the Item class.
For example:

Is there a way to make Doxygen recognize C# Collections?
If not, is there a workaround for this, that does not involve using Arrays instead of a Collection? (like a preprocessor that converts all instances of List<?> to ?[])
Edit:
Doxygen v1.12.0
Graphviz dot v12.0.0
Doxyfile diff:
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = ./Docs/
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_JAVA   = YES
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES  = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES     = YES
INPUT                  = ./Assets/Scripts/
RECURSIVE              = YES
HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET  = ./Docs/doxygen-awesome-css/doxygen-awesome.css
HTML_COLORSTYLE        = LIGHT
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = YES
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
HAVE_DOT               = YES
UML_LOOK               = YES
TEMPLATE_RELATIONS     = YES
CALL_GRAPH             = YES
CALLER_GRAPH           = YES
DIR_GRAPH_MAX_DEPTH    = 25
DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT       = svg
DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES    = 100

Small example, where ArrA gets a relation to ClassB drawn in the diagram, but ListA does not:
public class ClassB { 
}
public class ListA {
    List<ClassB> myList = new List<ClassB>();
}
public class ArrA {
    ClassB[] myArr = new ClassB[10];
}




Which version of doxygen are you using? Can you create a small, complete, example that shows the problem (including the used / changed doxygen settings i.e. the result of doxygen -x Doxyfile) and add it to the question

Added the requested information to the question

Looks like this is not considered by doxygen (and probably also not for equivalent cpp cases). Maybe best to create an issue at https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new/choose

As I understood (although I haven't tested it), Doxygen does have support for C++STL containers. I was hoping that Doxygen had something similar for C# collections.

No doxygen does not have such support, do you have a good source where a description of this for C# is?
